# Creating A Custom Listbox - Tkinter

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I am messing around with `tkinter` and I am trying to create a custom listbox. The code I have so far works but I would like to set a different default width for for this widget but I can't figure out how to do it. What I have now returns this error:

`AttributeError: 'ShelfListbox' object has no attribute 'tk'`

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from TestData import *
from Item import *
from Shelf import ShelfListbox

def create_item(lb):
    global item
    item = Item(sku_ent.get(), title_ent.get(), qty_ent.get())
    lb.insert(END, item.print_item())

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)

sku_lbl = Label(root, text="SKU: ").grid()
sku_ent = Entry(root)
sku_ent.grid(row=0, column=1)

title_lbl = Label(root, text="Title: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
title_ent = Entry(root)
title_ent.grid(row=1, column=1)

qty_lbl = Label(root, text="QTY: ").grid(row=2, column=0)
qty_ent = Entry(root)
qty_ent.grid(row=2, column=1)

item_list = ShelfListbox(root)
item_list.grid(row=0, rowspan=3, column=2)

for key in items:
    item_list.insert(END, items[key].print_item()) #ERROR COMES FROM THIS LINE

btn = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=lambda: create_item(item_list)).grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

The ShelfListbox code:

```
from tkinter import *


class ShelfListbox(Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Listbox.__init__(master, width=60)
```

Comment: can you show the whole stack trace? There's not enough information, and I'm not convinced the error is coming from the line you say it does, since that line would likely give you a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `self` as the first parameter to the `Listbox.__init__` method:

```
Listbox.__init__(self, master, width=60)
```